# How to reassign hotkeys in Chrome extention using JS?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have a working code:

```
document.onkeypress=function(e){   
    if( e.keyCode==49 ){
        e.preventDefault();
        alert('Переход на целевую страницу при нажатии 1');
        window.location.href="http://yandex.ru";
    } 
};
```

But it doesn't work if I try to assign key like <kbd>F1</kbd>, <kbd>F2</kbd>, <kbd>F3</kbd> Chrome opens Help (<kbd>F1</kbd>) and so on. `e.preventDefault();` doesn't work.
How can I update my code?

Comment: I believe you can do that without writing a code. Chrome has a function like that so you could input custom command.

Comment: I can use input custom command using a combination of keys Ctrl+Alt+d for example. But I need to use F1, F2, F3. And they are blocked...

Comment: I really have nothing one this, but this link should help some bit. [link](https://superuser.com/questions/497526/how-to-customize-google-chrome-keyboard-shortcuts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In some browsers keypress doesn't work but keydown works.  You may want to reference this: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/keys.html.

I hope this helps.

Comment: In my case keypress works...If I press "1" - it works, if I press F1 - it doesnt work...

Comment: No worries.  I am glad it helped :-)